# File accessing -Java or C++

Tags: c++, database

I have a lot of data kept in a file. Which one would be fastest for accessing some keywords from that file multiple times? Java or C++. Am I going to get some advantage in speed if I keep those data in a database like Sqlite compared to file operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C++ is a low-level language, while Java runs in a virtual machine, well-written C++ code will typically be faster than well-written Java code, especially for low-level operations (including file accesses). Java has significant overhead whenever it needs to perform an operation outside of its virtual machine.

For large amounts of data, a database will be much faster than direct file operation; it's exactly what a database is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use C++, because it compiles directly to native bytecode.  While some JVMs also do that, Java can't be guaranteed to always run that way.  A database language would be even better, like the Sqlite you mentioned, because the language is *specifically* optimized for database stuff.